# Compare hashes based and key and value, and return elements which are not common

Tags: ruby

I have a database of files in a given directory and their hashes, which I store in json format like so

```
{
    "file_hashes": {
        "./file1": [
            hash1,
            hash2,
            hash3
        ],
        "./file2": [
            hash1,
            hash2,
            hash3
        ]
    }
 }
```

and so on.

I need to take the checksums of files in a specified directory, and compare them to the database and return the elements (i.e., the files) which are NOT present in both hashes.

How can I efficiently compare two hashes and filter for the UNCOMMON elements?

Comment: Problem description is very vague.  Give a sample input and output to show exactly what you want to accomplish.  Show what code you've tried to write so far, and describe where it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to calculate a symmetric difference?

Given two hashes that may have pairs in common, and pairs not in common:

```
hash1 = {:a => :b, :c => :d}
hash2 = {:a => :b, :e => :f}
```

Intersection:

```
Hash[hash1.to_a & hash2.to_a]
=> {:a=>:b}
```

Union:

```
Hash[hash1.to_a | hash2.to_a]
=> {:a=>:b, :c=>:d, :e=>:f}
```

Symmetic Difference, calculated by using union - intersection:

```
Hash[(hash1.to_a | hash2.to_a) - (hash1.to_a & hash2.to_a)]
=> {:c=>:d, :e=>:f}
```

Symmetric Difference, calculated by using the union of differences:

```
Hash[(hash1.to_a - hash2.to_a) | (hash2.to_a - hash1.to_a)]
=> {:c=>:d, :e=>:f}
```

If your hashes are large, or nested, or have other complexities, you'll want to read about better solutions. Try the Ruby gem [**hashdiff**](https://github.com/liufengyun/hashdiff).